# video_player looping break

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-video-player

I want to use the video_player library in my project. I want to loop one video that has the same beginning and the end (same sound, same frame) but when looping it seems like there is a small break between the first and next playing of the video (half seconds maybe).
This results in video looping not being as smooth as required.

Can you please tell me if there is an argument to sort this out or some other solution, maybe another library?